# Excel DSUM - using AND/OR as part of the criteria

Tags: excel, criteria

I checked all the Dsum questions and they did not answer mine.

I have a DSUM formula in my spreadsheet that looks like this - =DSUM(Sheet1!$A:$L, Sheet3!$I1, Sheet3!$A1:$J2). A1 to J2 in Sheet 3 is a set of fields with corresponding values that the function tests against.

```
Name    Status  Ops Grade   Score   Amount  Date    Sum Description
         FAC                        BUDGET  1/1/2012
```

Now my issue is I need to exclude certain names from the sum. I worked around by including another column in B1 that excludes all names with 'AL' in them. This is not scalable as I'm forced to create a column for each combination that needs to be excluded.

```
Name    Name    Status  Ops Grade   Score   Amount  Date    Sum Description
       <>*AL*   FAC                         BUDGET  1/1/2012
```

Is it possible to include OR/AND in the Name values? e.g. =<>*80*or <>AB* or <>()* etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to include the criteria in the same table as the data. You can use another table for the criteria.

- For each criterion for the same field add a new row in the criteria table (like above).
- If you need an `OR` put criteria on different rows. If you need and `AND` put criteria on the same row. For multiple criteria on the same field, you need to add multiple columns.

```
Name
<>*80*
<>AB*
<>()*
```

More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dsum-function-53181285-0c4b-4f5a-aaa3-529a322be41b).

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. The criteria is in Sheet3 and the data is in Sheet1. Sorry for the confusion. I have 10 columns in the criteria with atleast one column having a condition. My question was for multiple conditions on the same field, would I have to create multiple columns for each condition or use an AND/OR in the one cell under that column.

Comment: If possible I would load the spreadsheet I'm working with. The Dsum sheet I have is massive. There are about 12 critirea ranges for each month twice that for Budget and Purchases. There are also 15 exclusions that could grow. Adding rows or columns for each exclusion would be a maintenance nightmare. I guess I'm just looking for a more scalable solution be it with DSUm or SumIF or any other function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try looking into the SUMPRODUCT formula.  It can do some crazy stuff like making a truth table and applying it across a Range of values, even across 2 dimensions.  But if the spreadsheet is too large it might have performance issues.  I feel your pain though, I have some sheets that go all the way to XFD.

Comment: @david.s Can you post an updated link? The current one goes to a Microsoft "Sorry, the page you’re looking for can’t be found" page.